# How do i install jquery time ago plugin

Tags: jquery, timeago

I can't seem to get the jquery time ago plugin to work.

Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.timeago.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <abbr class="timeago" title="19 March 2013 04:51:33 PM"></abbr>
</body>
</html>
```

It don't seem to be working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to initiate the plugin
like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $("abbr.timeago").timeago()

});
```

the final code will be like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.timeago.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <abbr class="timeago" title="19 March 2013 04:51:33 PM"></abbr>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $("abbr.timeago").timeago()

    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
```

Make sure you follow the instructions from http://timeago.yarp.com/ (See *How?* section)